# Whats the best practice for custom form fields and validation?

Tags: angular

I'm building a component library and need to make a decision on form field validation.

My company is building a custom theme and as part of that, form fields are custom.

They have validation messages, validation colours, etc.

I'm of the mind of creating self contained input fields

```
<app-custom-input
    [(value)]="fieldString"
    [validations]="{
        required: { message: 'Field is required' }
     }">
</app-custom-input>

Or

<app-custom-input
    [(value)]="fieldString"
    [validations]="[
       { 
           validator: Validators.required, 
           message: 'Field is required'
       }
    ]">
</app-custom-input>
```

If the field doesn't match the validation items, the field changes it's styles, appends the message, etc and all of this happens internally. Externally, you just have a string value and no worries.

I've seen some examples where people repeat the mark up that makes up a form field, messages, hints, errors, etc.

Any best practices? Anything wrong with the first method?

Comment: Is this a very specific input form, e.g. for a email? If so why providing the error msg. If not. How does you internal validator work for all different input. E.g only numbers or email. So all I wanna say, why providing an error msg but not a validator.

Comment: @ChristianLutz, I just added a second example that uses validation functions directly. In the first example, I intended to map the validation functions internally, within the input field. The custom input component would would be a base input component, that you would interact with as if it were a native input element. You could later wrap it in specialised elements like `custom-input-email`, which would have it's own presets - like an email icon and default validation - but that's not really important

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar thing by building wrappers around the native form controls and consolidating the custom validations via user defined data-types in only 1 file.

What i did was as follows :

`Custom Input Field Component` would accept a data-type and pass it to Validator Service (see below).

Made a validator service in angular which would take in the name of the data type and look it up from a json file to bring out the constraints like `max` , `min` , `length` , `required` , `pattern` and build a form control out of it which gets used up by the `Custom Input Field Component`.

```
attachValidator(datatype, extras = null , name) {

let min_len
let max_len
let max
let min
let allowed_values
let spans
let pattern
let validators = []
let type = this.typeService.getTypeAttrs(datatype)

for (let key in type) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'max_value': { max = type[key]; validators.push(this.maxValidator(max)); } break;
    case 'min_value': { min = type[key]; validators.push(this.minValidator(min)); } break;
    case 'allowed_values': { allowed_values = type[key]; validators.push(this.allowedValuesValidator(allowed_values)) } break;
    case 'max_decimals': { spans = type[key]; validators.push(this.decValidator(spans)) } break;
    case 'pattern': { spans = type[key];pattern = spans; validators.push(this.patternValidator(spans)) } break;
    case 'min_length': { spans = type[key];validators.push(Validators.minLength(spans)) } break;
    case 'max_length': { spans = type[key];validators.push(Validators.maxLength(spans)) } break;

  }
}

for (let key in extras) {
  if (extras[key] != undefined) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'required': { if (extras[key]) { validators.push(Validators.required) } } break;
      case 'integer': { if (extras[key]) { validators.push(this.isInteger()) } } break;

    }
  }
}
return [new FormControl(name, validators) , Validators.compose(validators) , pattern]
  }
```

Below HTML is my custom Input Text component having all of the `Control_Value_Accessor` jugglery behind it.

You can have generic markup for your error fields like this

```
<mat-form-field [floatPlaceholder]="float" *ngIf="!isDisabled">
<mat-placeholder>
    <span style="font-size:1.18em;">{{label}}</span>
</mat-placeholder>
<input #txtip="ngModel" [ngClass]="{readonly : checkMode() == true}" type="{{inputtype}}" matInput [minlength]="min_length" [maxlength]="max_length" [(ngModel)]="value" name="{{name}}" [required]="required" [pattern]="pattern"
    [readonly]="checkMode()" [errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher" (blur)="emitBlur()">

<mat-hint>
    <strong>{{placeholder}}</strong>
</mat-hint>
<mat-error *ngIf="showErrors || txtip.invalid">
    <ui-message [showIcons]='false' [msgs]="errorMsgs"></ui-message>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This has very sparse information for your question but relevant , i have done abit more than this . Do feel free to comment and ask if you find the answer confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Very often I have the same goals as you described. You said about splitting full input logic (including hints, validation behavior and so on) to separate component, and it's what I usually do. It looks rather elegant I think, so finally in component with form you have no more logic than when you deal with simple `input`s, and all other logic is encapsulated in repeated child components with inputs itself. All that you need, is to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface in child component, and you can bind input values in parent component via regular `[(ngModel)]`. You can find a bunch of tutorials about implementing `ControlValueAccessor` interface, but first time I followed this one: http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel. At first sight it looks a little complex, but when you will write this logic few times, it will become simple.